# Failed to load dynamic library 'libolm.so'

Tags: flutter, dart, matrix, mobile-application

I'm buidlind an chat application using matrix sdk package **[matrix: ^0.22.3]** in flutter. If i use that matrix package in my app, I'm getting an error mentioned below, kindly help me to fix this issue, I tried for last one week but I can't fix this issue, anyone know this issue help me to fix this.

**ERROR:

`Error initializing encryption Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'libolm.so': dlopen failed: library "libolm.so" not found`**

1. I've tried changing the version of matrix and tried lots of time.
2. Changing the minVersion in the build.gradle file.
3. Sent mail to the package manager.
4. And also tried running:

`flutter clean` 
`flutter pub get` 
`flutter run`

Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you add `flutter_olm` as it says in the readme? https://github.com/famedly/matrix-dart-sdk